# How to log sizes of each block

Tags: bitcoind

I am looking to do some research on the blockchain, is there anyway to easily the size of each block while i download it - i have seen graphs from coinbase etc, but these are not accurate for me as for the first 12 months they put the blockchain size as 0MB - Any ideas welcome, i have looked through the log file of bitcoin during the download and while it gives me data about the number of tx in the block etc it doesn't contain the size

Answer (score 1):

What you can do it traverse back from the chain tip via RPC:

1. call `getbestblockhash` (RPC)
2. Use blockhash to call `getblock` (RPC)
3. Read `size` -> store it somewhere (CSV file, etc.)
4. Read `previousblockhash` and use it as blockhash for `getblock`
5. Goto step 2